# Android Driver not working in appium

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am new to Appium and was trying on android device, so while writing code I want to use Android Driver but everytime error comes up, check the error below

"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-HT0VM72', ip: '192.168.88.104', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:485)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByName(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:110)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByName(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByName(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:303)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at demo.TestCase1.main(TestCase1.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:415)
    ... 13 more"

but if i replace AndroidDriver with RemoveWebDriver it works fine? why? 
"Appium version 1.4.16.1 (Ophiuchus)"

package demo;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class TestCase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Fever 4G");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.vector.guru99");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.vector.guru99.BaseActivity");
        driver =new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //verification1
        if(driver.findElement(By.name("Guru99")).isDisplayed())
            System.out.println("guru99 header is displayed");
        else 
            System.out.println("guru99 is not displayed");

        //verification2
        if(driver.findElement(By.name("Course Category")).isSelected())
            System.out.println("Course category is currently selected");
        else 
            System.out.println("Course Category is not selected");

        //Get all the courses listed in the course category
        List<WebElement> courseoffered=driver.findElements(By.id("com.vector.guru99:id/lblListHeader"));
        System.out.println("Course offered are :");
        for(WebElement course : courseoffered)
        {
            String cours= course.getText();
            System.out.println(cours);
            if(course.isEnabled())
                System.out.println("  is Enabled ");
            else
                System.out.println("  is not Enabled");

        }
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what appium java client version you are using, but first:

driver.findElement(**By.name**("Course Category")).isSelected()

**Note**: Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for Appium session since version 1.5, and if you will use latest client version you will get `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException` with explaining details.

While using latest server/client combination (1.7.1, 5.0.4 java), there is no problem of using both cases you mentioned:

`RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);`

or

`AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url, capabilities);`

Both work for finding elements and there attributes.

Comment: appium java client version was 5.0.4, and the main issue to ask query is i cannot use "driver.scrollTo("SAP BI"); "  and should i change my appium server or tell me how Scroll to will work

Comment: First: make sure you are using appium server version at least 1.7 since you are using he latest client. Second: create instance of driver like `Android driver = new AndroidDriver(url, capabilities);` and to scroll to element you need to do it like `driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"SAP BI\").instance(0)))");`

Comment: i have downloaded appium server 1.7.1 and the moment i click on it, it is force closing, can u suggest me the solution. i am using windows 10

Comment: Update question with the code you run, appium server log and formatted stacktrace. Not clear what's your issue for now + stacktrace is messy, apply formating

Comment: before executing the code you have to start the appium server, i used the above code only and when i open Appium v1.7.1 GUI and click on start server, it is crashing. Suggest me the ways to correct it or different ways if any to start the server.